# Show that this quasi-geodesic ray is not Gromov hyperbolic?

Tags: geodesic, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Consider the spiral (t, log(1+t)) (given in polar coordinates); it inherits the Euclidean metric from the plane. I have to show that this spiral (a quasi-geodesic) is not Gromov hyperbolic. In other words, it isn't  hyperbolic for any  > 0. I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. My professor suggested that I should use the 4-point condition, but I haven't gotten anywhere with that either. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd first change of parameter to write as $(e^\theta-1,\theta)$. Then check what happens for the four points given by $\theta=2k\pi$, $2k\pi+\pi/2$, $2k\pi+\pi$, $2k\pi+3\pi/2$. (Computations would be simpler using the curve $(t,\log t)_{t\ge 1}$ which is very close to this one...)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I tried those four sets of points and didn't get anywhere. Regardless of how I labeled them, the four point condition seemed to hold.

Comment: I did the computations as well with these 4 points and it worked...

Comment: And I did some experiments confirming this. For instance, for the points $p_k=\theta+k\pi/2$ $(k=0,1,2,3)$ and $\theta=20\pi$, the approx values of $p_1p_2+p_3p_4,p_1p_3+p_2p_4,p_1p_4+p_2p_3$ are $4.29e26$, $5.07e26$, $4.28e26$ so $p1p3+p2p4$ is (additively) much higher than the other two (and this just confirms the analytic rigorous computation, which is an easy exercise).

Comment: Got ya. I think I didn't run the theta value high enough in order to see a significant difference. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, I did your calculations, but for both p1p3+p2p4 and p1p4+p2p3 I got 2.49e29.

Comment: Oh, the result I wrote was for $\theta=2k\pi$ with $k=9$, not $k=10$ (I got confused because in did for $k$ in range(1,10), which in SageMath finishes by 9). But well for $k=10$, i.e., $\theta=20\pi$, I get the numbers $2.29e29$, $2.71e29$, $2.61e29$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Step 1. Show that your spiral is Hausdorff-close to the spiral $S$ given in polar coordinates by the parameteric equation
$$
(r, \log(r)), r\ge 1. 
$$

Step 2. Verify that the spiral $S$ is not 0-hyperbolic.

Step 3. Verify that the spiral $S$ maps into itself under the sequence of dilations
$$
f_n: (r, \theta)\mapsto (e^{2\pi n} r, \theta), n\in {\mathbb N},
$$
i.e. $f_n(S)\subset S$ for each $n$.

Step 4. Combine steps 2 and 3 to conclude that $S$ is not $\delta$-hyperbolic for any $\delta<\infty$.

Step 5. Make the same conclusion for the original spiral using Step 1 and your knowledge (I assume you know this staff) that the 4-point hyperbolicity is preserved under $(1,C)$-quasi-isometries.